# How do I pass multipart-form data to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, image-upload, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to send a file from client side and receive it through AWS API Gateway to my Lambda function which will then put this file in S3 bucket.

I have used the following as default parameter template in API Gateway

```
{"image" : $input.params('MediaUrl0')}
```

How will I receive it in python which looks like:
def read_upload_toS3(event, context):
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

Answer (score 5):

You could use the lately introduced [`$input.body`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference) variable in your mapping template:

```
{
  "body" : "$input.body"
}
```

You maybe should also check out [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228067) discussion on this problem. To receive the body in your python function just do

```
def my_handler(event, context):
    body = event['body']
```

---

But if the sole purpose of the function is to upload the file to S3, you could also do this directly with API Gateway:

- Go to the **Integration Request** settings of your method
- Under **Integration Type** klick *show advanced*
- Select **AWS Service Proxy**
- Select **S3** als the AWS Service and fill in the necessary information

Comment: I would like to know how to receive this in the Python.

Comment: I got this error. Can you please help me with this..    {"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\'-\' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value\n at [Source: [B@98c32b3; line: 1, column: 3]"}

Comment: I have the same error. It seems api gateway still can't properly handle multipart-form data

Comment: Try `{ "body" : "$util.base64Encode($input.body)" }` if you're getting an error.

Comment: "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character..."   can be solved by adding a "multipart/form-data" body template in the "Integration Request" section of your POST resource.
(A spanish/speaking video made by me: https://youtu.be/79ckseUxvLw)

Comment: Its been years for this question and still I am facing the issue. Why AWS not working on this...?? Anyone with the trick...?? I am getting this in `$input.json($)` as `----------------------------688578637414600670323347\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"\r\n\r\nfilename.json\r\n----------------------------688578637414600670323347--`